# Pandas Average If Across Multiple Columns

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas, I'd like to calculate the average age and weight for people playing each sport. I know I can loop, but was wondering what the most efficient way is.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [0, 1, 0, 30, 150],
    [1, 1, 1, 25, 200],
    [1, 0, 0, 20, 175]
], columns=[
    "Plays Basketball",
    "Plays Soccer",
    "Plays Football",
    "Age",
    "Weight"
])
```

| Plays Basketball | Plays Soccer | Plays Football | Age | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 30 | 150 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 25 | 200 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 20 | 175 |

I tried `groupby` but it creates a group for every possible combination of sports played. I just need an average age and weight for each sport.

Result should be:

|  | Age | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Plays Basketball | 22.5 | 187.5 |
| Plays Soccer | 27.5 | 175.0 |
| Plays Football | 25.0 | 200.0 |

Comment: please show your groupby code

Comment: `df.groupby(["Plays Basketball", "Plays Soccer", "Plays Football"]).mean()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [`dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) product and normalize by the count to get the mean:

```
df2 = df.filter(like='Plays')

out = df2.T.dot(df[['Age', 'Weight']]).div(df2.sum(), axis=0)
```

Output:

```
                   Age  Weight
Plays Basketball  22.5   187.5
Plays Soccer      27.5   175.0
Plays Football    25.0   200.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use one groupby for each column you want to summarize:

```py
import pandas as pd

indicators = ["Plays Basketball", "Plays Soccer", "Plays Football"]
rows = []
keep_cols = ["Age", "Weight"]
for indicator in indicators:
    average = df.groupby(indicator).mean()
    rows.append(average.loc[1][keep_cols].rename(indicator))
output = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

Comment: Thanks Nick. This definitely works. Wondering if there's a better/more efficient way without looping.